# Unable to correctly add labels to a list of ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, geom-text, do.call

I am trying to assemble a multipanel boxplot with ggplot.
To have a general structure I am generating a list of plots and plotting them. I also want to add letters reporting significance groups for each boxplot.
Everything works fine, except for the fact that all the boxplots show the letters computed during the last iteration of the loop.

I post below an example in which I just try to add letters reporting the loop iteration number, and as you can see instead of reporting "Plot 1" for the first loop and "Plot 2" for the second it always plots the second.

[image: Plot with wrong letters]

The code I used is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
mydata<-data.frame(values=c(1,4,5,6,4,2,4,7,3,4,5,6,4,4,2,1,3,6,4,1,2,5,4,3,4,2,1,3,4,2),group=c(rep("A",15),rep("B",15)))
mydata2<-data.frame(values=c(2,6,5,6,7,2,5,7,3,4,5,6,4,4,2,1,3,6,4,1,2,5,4,3,1,2,3,3,4,7),group=c(rep("A",15),rep("B",15)))
myp<-list()
for(aaa in 1:2)
{
if(aaa==1) mydata<-mydata else mydata<-mydata2
myp[[aaa]]<-ggplot(mydata, aes(x=group, y=values)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + #avoid plotting outliers twice
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y=max(values)-0.05*max(values),label=paste("Plot",aaa))) +
  geom_text(aes(x=2, y=max(values)-0.05*max(values),label=paste("Plot",aaa)))
}
do.call(grid.arrange,myp)
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like the used of do.call with grid.arrange creates problems with the geom_text (but not with the plot, which is different in the two loops).
I would prefer NOT to manually write all the plot functions, since I have at lest three multipanel plots each on with 4 boxplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what goes wrong with `geom_text`, but everything works if you use `annotate` instead (which should be used exactly for this purpose).

```
for(aaa in 1:2){
  print(aaa)
  if(aaa==1) df<-mydata else df<-mydata2
  myp[[aaa]]<-ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=values)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + #avoid plotting outliers twice
    geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0)) +
    annotate("text", x=1, y=max(df$values)-0.05*max(df$values),label=paste("Plot",aaa)) +
    annotate("text", x=2, y=max(df$values)-0.05*max(df$values),label=paste("Plot",aaa))
}
```

[image: example]